# How to center my div

Tags: html, center

I've googled this many times, and I cant understand why my div wont center.

HTML:

```
<body><div id="mydiv"></div></body>
```

css

```
*{
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
}           
html,body{height:100%; width:100%;}

#mydiv{ 
            height:50%;
            width:50%;
            background:grey;
            margin:auto;

}
```

It only centers horizontally and wont center vertically, whats the problem because im not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
#mydiv { 
    height:50%;
    width:50%;
    background:grey;
    position:absolute;
    top:25%;
    left:25%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need vertical centering too, refer to the Dead Centre approach, you will need a few extra `<div>`s but it should help!

http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html

Answer (score 1):

Hopely useful for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ug3RM/

```
#mydiv{ 
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        height:50%;
        width:50%;
        margin-top:-25%;
        margin-left:-25%;
        background:grey;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To vertical align you can try setting your margin like so:

```
#myDiv{margin:50% auto;}
```

Of course this will depend on your containing elements. However if the markup is as you have provided, it should display vertically aligned in the center...

Comment: That's actually putting 50% of the parent container between the top of the child and the top of the parent; thus, leaving 0% below the bottom of the child. ie (50/50/50...150% tall) - with a child that's 50% tall.

Answer (score 0):

OP,

Check [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gRqn/). Centers both vertically and horizontally.

Uses the `display:table` and `display:table-cell` approach, which conveniently allows for `vertical-align: middle` to be paired with `margin: auto`.

Hope it helps.